# How do I display an integer from a database object in Django?

Tags: django, database, integer

I am a beginner in Django and coding in general. I know that this must be an easy thing to do but I have been struggling with this for days.

This is my model:

```
class Bal(models.Model):
balance = models.IntegerField(default='5000')

def __int__(self):
    return "{}, {}".format(self.pk, self.balance)
```

View:

```
def add_stock(request):
import requests
...

bala = Bal.objects.get(pk=2)

'''

    return render(request, 'stocktrader/add_stock.html', {'ticker': ticker, 'output': output, 'bala': bala})
```

in the html page:

```
<h4>Balance: {{ bala }}</h4>
```

The output on the web page is:

```
Balance: Bal object (2)
```

Where "Bal object(2)" is I need it to display a number.

The table in the database has one 'balance' entry for 5000 and it has an id if 2. I just don't understand how to get the value of '5000' to display instead of 'Bal object (2)'.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe

```
<h4>Balance: {{ bala.balance }}</h4>
```

should work? :)

Comment: thank you very much. I knew it would be something simple.

Comment: Wellcome. You have to take a look at ORM. By the way it could be nice if you select this as answer if it worked. :)